# How can I access this object in typeahead?

Tags: javascript, laravel, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using twitter typeahead with Laravel 5.3. Just so you know, here's my data for a product and along with its manufacturer brand(FK):

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "iphone",
    "created_at": "2017-02-08 06:12:34",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-08 06:12:34",
    "user_id": 1,
    "brand_id": 1,
    "msds_url": "google.com",
    "gravity": 1.03,
    "recipe_id": null,
    "relevance": 210,
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "apple",
      "created_at": "2017-02-08 03:00:49",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-08 03:00:49",
      "user_id": 1,
      "abbreviation": "AP",
      "visible": 1
    }
  }
]
```

When the remote source JSON array gets mapped to a js object array called `value`, the data in the suggestion dropdown gets formatted the way it's written e.g. 'Apple - iPhone'.

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    wildcard: '%QUERY',
    url: '/find?q=%QUERY%',
    transform: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
      // Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
      return $.map(response, function(product) {
        return {
          value: product.brand.name+' - '+product.name,
          other: product
        };
      });
    }
  }
});

// Instantiate the Typeahead UI
$('#search').typeahead( null,{
  display: 'value',//choose a key from the map
  highlight: true,
  hint: true,
  source: engine
});
```

What I also want to do is cast the `brand.id` which would be 1, and the `product.id` which would be 2, into some data attributes on the same input, so I captured the event and logged the 'selected suggestion' that the user took.

```
$("#search").on("typeahead:select", function(ev, suggestion) {
    console.log(suggestion);
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't give me access to the full array of data because it's formatted specifically within the map function from the bloodhound part

```
// Map the remote source JSON array to a JavaScript object array
          return $.map(response, function(product) {
            return {
              value: product.brand.name+' - '+product.name, //this format
              other: product //full access to object
            };
          });
```

So I switched the `display` to `other` instead of `value` so that the full object gets passed instead of the brand name and product name.

```
$('#search').typeahead( null,{
  //display: 'value',
  display: 'other',
  highlight: true,
  hint: true,
  source: engine
});
```

Now when a suggestion comes up in the dropdown, it will say `[object object]` because I haven't accessed it yet unlike before.

How can I access the object and format it properly and keep access to the brand id and product id? This is so that later when I submit the form, I can match the selected product id's with my product table items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I have not checked the codes but I have this working in my project. Try this:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
        var result = Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.name);
        if (datum.brand != null){
            result = result.concat(Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.brand.name));
        }
        return result;
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        url: '/find?q=%QUERY%',
        prepare: function(query, settings) {
            settings.type = "GET";
            settings.dataType = "json"
            settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', encodeURIComponent(query));
            return settings;
        }
    }
});

engine.initialize();

$("#search").typeahead(null, {
    name: 'engine',
    displayKey: function(data){
        return  data.name + (data.brand ? " - " + data.brand.name : "");
    },
    source: engine.ttAdapter(),
})
.on('typeahead:selected', function($e, datum){
    //You may access the value object here
    console.log("datum" ,datum);
});
```

Let me know if works OK?

Comment: Works perfect!!! Please add some explanation to your code though as I and no doubt others will wish to understand how it works bit by bit.

Comment: Well, I had implemented it 3-4 years ago and since then I have never go through the documentation as I have never changed this codes and did not find any problem with it, but looking into your codes, I think the problem was there in map function that manipulates the data and in ```source: engine``` statement.